# Populate related objects in WebAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

We're working on a WebAPI application with Entity Framework 6. We have a few classes similar to these:

```
class Level0:
    public virtual IList<Level1> Level1s {get; set;}

class Level1: 
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Level0 Parent { get; set; }
    public int Level2Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Level2 Level2 {get; set;}

class Level2:
    public int Level3Id { get; set;}
    public virtual Level3 Level3 {get; set;}

class Level3: ...
```

The frontend passes a Level0, whose JSON looks like this:

```
{
    Level1s: [
        { Level2Id: 4 },
        { Level2Id: 12 },
    ]
}
```

The model binder indeed gives as a `Level0` instance. It has a `Level1s` list with two elements, both have their `Level2Id` property set, and both ids have corresponding records in the database. The `Level2` property, however, is null, and even though it's virtual, we can't do something like:

```
level0.Level1s.Where(l1=>l1.Level2.Level3.SomeProp==5).Sum(...)
```

We are getting an exception because `l1.Level2` is null.

It's as if the lazy fetch mechanism doesn't kick in. Dropping the `virtual` didn't work, either. Is there a way to either preload all the related objects, or convince the lazy fetch mechanism to work?

We circumvented the issue by loading all the `Level2` and `Level3` objects from the database ourselves, but it's rather ugly.

Comment: Are you attaching the passed Level0 instance to your DbContext? Without that step, EF will never kick in.

Comment: Oh, yes. `context.Entry(level0).State = EntityState.Modified` (in this particular controller function, we are modifying an existing object). `context` has `DbSet`s of all relevant types.